# What is SLG resolution in Prolog?

Tags: prolog, prolog-metainterpreter

I want to understand how does SLG resolution work. But I don't know what SLG is (what does it stand for?).

The resource I found are [Query evaluation under the well-founded semantics](https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.1145/153850.153865) and citation to `Efficient implementation of general logical queries` by W. Chen, D.S. Warren and `Implementations of the well founded semantics` by W. Chen, T. Swift, D.S. Warren (there should a meta-intepreter from Quintus in it). But it's a bit too abstract or I can't access it.

Prolog engines propose SLG resolution as tabling but I would like to implement a meta-interpreter that does SLG resolution.

Any hint for a definition that would help me to implement the meta-interpreter is welcome.

Comment: "*This paper presents a partial deduction framework for query evaluation,
called SLG resolution (Linear resolution with Selection function for General
logic programs).*" - from a paper [Tabled Evaluation with Delaying for General
Logic Programs](https://dl.acm.org/doi/pdf/10.1145/227595.227597) by Chen and Warren, 1996. That seems to be where it was introduced, so it appears to stand for "Selective Linear General" (compared to SLD "Selective Linear Definite"), for whatever help that is.